# How to implement Concurrency in EF code first while using a TPT hierarchy

Tags: .net, inheritance, sql-server-ce, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Hey everyone! I'm trying to implement optimistic concurrency check with the Entity Framework Code first (installed via nuget, so I assume its the last RC). However, I can't seem to make it work. I have the following class hierarchy

```
public abstract class DbEntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Autogenerated primary key for the object
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    protected DbEntityBase()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    //Some override for equality, omitted for brievity
}

public class Drawing : DbEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Just an implementation of ICollection<DrawingVersion>
    public DrawingVersionCollection Versions { get; private set; }

    public Drawing()
    {
        Name = "New Drawing";
        Versions = new DrawingVersionCollection(this);         
    }

}

public class DrawingVersion : DbEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Started { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    public DrawingFile File { get; private set; }

    public Drawing Owner { get; internal set; }

    internal DrawingVersion()
    {
        Name = "New Version";
        Started = DateTime.Now;
        LastModified = DateTime.Now;
        File = new DrawingFile();
    }
}
```

I'm using the following DbContext to persists them

```
public class PortfolioContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Drawing> Drawings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Key mapping
        modelBuilder.Entity<DbEntityBase>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);

        //Table Mapping
        modelBuilder.Entity<DrawingVersion>().ToTable("DrawingVersion");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Drawing>().ToTable("Drawing");

        //Ignored fields
        modelBuilder.Entity<DrawingVersion>()
            .Ignore(v => v.Owner);
    }
}
```

All this work fine and dandy. If I check the generated schema, I see to table, one for Drawing and one for for DrawingVersion. I can read, update and delete without any problems.

The problem appeared when I wanted to add a timestamp to my entities. At first I did the naive thing. I added the following in DbEntityBase

```
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

And those line in my context

```
        //Versionning mapping
        modelBuilder.Entity<DbEntityBase>()
            .Property(e => e.Timestamp)
            .IsConcurrencyToken()
            .HasColumnType("timestamp")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

However, during the schema generation, it fail with the following exception

> System.NotSupportedException : The
>   store generated pattern 'Computed' is
>   not supported for properties that are
>   not of type 'timestamp'  or
>   'rowversion'.

At that point I was a little sacarstic. "Well gee, that just so me, putting *timestamp* in the column type while I should have put *timestamp* instead". I tried putting 'rowversion' instead, put it still didn't work. I also tried the TimestampAttribute directly on the property, but same error.

I tried to put the timestamp data on the child classes, but then I hit the following exception

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException
>   : One or more validation errors were
>   detected during model generation
>
> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : Type
>   'Portfolio.Repositories.Drawing' is
>   derived from the type
>   'Portfolio.Repositories.DbEntityBase'
>   that is the type for EntitySet
>   'PortfolioContext.DbEntityBases'. Type
>   'Portfolio.Repositories.Drawing'
>   defines new concurrency requirements
>   that are not allowed for sub types of
>   base EntitySet types.

So I guess I can't do that either.

I must say, I am very confused. Why is the exception telling me that I should use a timestamp, as it is exactly what I am doing? Could that be a bug in the framework? If no, is their any other way to add concurrency checking with a Table PerType mapping?

I am using SQL Serve Ce 4.0 as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem in defining TPC inheritance. You must modify your child entities mapping to use mapping from the parent entity:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<DrawingVersion>()
                .Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties())
                .ToTable("DrawingVersion");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Drawing>()
                .Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties())
                .ToTable("Drawing");

    ...
}
```